# OMXPLAYER pause seek for 6secs with --live

Tags: raspberry-pi, omxplayer

When i use the live parameter in my command line like this :

```
omxplayer -o hdmi http://www.example.com/video.mp4 --live
```

If I press "p" the video is paused but seek +6s.

I doesn't have the problem when i doesn't use the live parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system - which raspi?

Comment: I use a raspberry pi 3 with Raspbian, fully updated

Answer (score 0):

Use `--loop` instead of `--live`
Try this one:

```
omxplayer -o hdmi --loop http://www.example.com/video.mp4
```

In my experiences the --live command doesn't do anything at all.